# Cron job which runs every 5 seconds

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

I need to create an cron job with the following functionality:

> The job should go to a particular directory and touch one file every 5 seconds. It should run for only 1 minute. The logic is to change the timestamp of the file.

I've come up with the following logic:

I have created the below cron job:

`00-01 09 * * * /home/flexsys/test.sh`

(the job will start at 9:00 and run up till 9:01)

The script contents is as follows:

```
        #!/bin/tcsh
        cd /home/A/B/C/
              while true
              do
              sleep 5
              touch ABC.txt
              done
```

I don't understand what to put in which condition tab. 
I have tried this through without the looping clause but it only touches the file once. I need to do it repeatedly until 9:01. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron running job every 15 seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11102/44425)

Answer (score 3):

```
00-01 09 * * * /home/flexsys/test.sh (the job will start at 9:00 and run upto 9:01)
```

That is not what this means.  This means the job will run at 9am **and** run again at 9:01.  Cron has no concept of killing jobs, only starting them.

---

As for the `while`, you need to run the `date` command, find the number of minutes, and test if it is or isn't `00`.  On my system

`date | cut -c12-19`

returns the full time, 12:36:28.  You'll need to figure out how to `cut` only the minutes out of the `date` output on your system.

Finally, you need the `test` command to determine if that value is equal to 0 or not.

Another option is that if your script needs to run for exactly 60 seconds, and you have to do something every five seconds, then you can just do your action a specific number of times and then exit.

---

The final problem you face is that the `ls` command on most, if not all, Unix systems does not display the timestamp down to the second.  You will most likely need an external tool or a `perl` script to verify that your file's timestamp is being updated every five seconds.  I'm not in a position to help you with that.

Comment: Why use `cut` if you can get seconds straight from `date` command by adding a relevant format switch? `date +'%S'` and you get the seconds without any further hassle.

Comment: `stat` will get you the timestamp. Look at the outputs for `ls -l /var/log/syslog`, `stat --format '%y == %Y' /var/log/syslog`, and `TZ=UTC stat --format '%y == %Y' /var/log/syslog` or for any other file.

Answer (score 1):

00 09 * * * /home/flexsys/test.sh

```
#!/bin/tcsh
    cd /home/A/B/C/
          @ a = 0
          while ( $a != 12 )
              sleep 5
              touch ABC.txt
              @ a = $a + 1
          end
```

This will run your script only once, but it  will touch your file 12 times with a 5 seconds pause between each touch. As long as 12*5 is 60, you'll have 1 minute of script runtime (unless you're on a slow filesystem, e.g. slow NFS)