# Run A Cron Job Task Every 30 Seconds

Tags: cron, cpanel

It's possible to set the cron job tool in my website cpanel 'VPS Hosting' to execute php file every 30 second 
I am using it to execute php file once at a minute `*,*,*,*,*` but I need to set it to run twice  in minute 
I have tried `1/2,*,*,*,*` but it's not working.

Comment: To keep it precisely, not a dublicate; it's 30 seconds not 15 ;-) ^^

Comment: i provide a different answer than given here or at the every-15-second question. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205717/105631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you run a shell script which runs your command, like:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
start:
mycommand >> /tmp/output
sleep 30
goto start
```

As someone else said, `cron` has a granularity of 1 minute.

Comment: Ned64, IMHO will be good to create your script proof from more than one run. Otherwise will become very interesting DoS tool :)

Comment: Romeo, Yes, that would be a nice feature.  If the command is executed manually, though, and not called by `cron`, it could be OK.  Let's see what Ashraf thinks.

Comment: If you want an easy way to proof the script from running with multiple instances, you can use flock as is demonstrated [here](http://jdimpson.livejournal.com/5685.html). This is Bash of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can't exec cron with increment less than minute. You can search for other schedulers. Or consider to create daemon which will have internal scheduler for such interval